# Stop Service, Stop activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am trying to complete my application. But I have a bug that hurts my head.

When I compile my AVD I have no bug but using my application on my android, the crach application. here is the code behind my Boutton stop which terminates the application that should probably be at the origin of the problem.

Please help.
I compile the application in my Android Device.

```
 public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
MediaPlayer player;
    int delay = 0;
    boolean isFirstTime = true;
    int period = 0;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    period = 60000;

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.son1);
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
    /***************Repete la sonnerie****************/
    Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
          if (isFirstTime) {
           isFirstTime = false;
           player.start();
          }
          else{
              player.start();
          }
      }
      }, delay, period);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    player.start();
}
```

}

LogCat

```
02-05 11:36:50.237: D/MyService(2473): onDestroy
02-05 11:37:10.647: W/dalvikvm(2473): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
02-05 11:37:10.657: E/AndroidRuntime(2473): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
02-05 11:37:10.657: E/AndroidRuntime(2473): java.lang.IllegalStateException
02-05 11:37:10.657: E/AndroidRuntime(2473):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
02-05 11:37:10.657: E/AndroidRuntime(2473):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:960)
02-05 11:37:10.657: E/AndroidRuntime(2473):     at com.sms.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:51)
02-05 11:37:10.657: E/AndroidRuntime(2473):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: Include your log cat exception

Comment: in my avd, i've no problem. i'll put it my log cat data

Comment: What is that? seriously? wheres the stack trace?

Comment: post your total log cat, not just one line

Comment: ok sorry, i've update.

Comment: nope, still no stacktrace

Comment: There is no crash in your logcat.. Put full logcat output with Error (it should be wrote "FATAL EXCEPTION" somewhere...)

Comment: what is it you don't understand in `Include your log cat exception`? (this is a real question although after reading it I realize it may sound sarcastic, but this could simply be a matter of communication).

Comment: Nothing.I was surprised. i can put a picture if u want

Comment: @andrey - the emulator can be unpredictable. If you could run this on a real device and send us the log cat from there it will be much better

Comment: ok I will do it. I put either a new post or edit this post. excuse for my bad english, j'espere que vous me comprennez. Merci

Comment: Don't open a new question, you'll get in trouble for spamming, update this one

Comment: ok really thank you for your advice. i'll dot it probably tomorow

Comment: I've update my post. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
MediaPlayer player;
    int delay = 0;
    boolean isFirstTime = true;
    int period = 0;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask tt;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    period = 60000;

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.son1);
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
    /***************Repete la sonnerie****************/
    timer = new Timer();
    tt = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isFirstTime) {
                   isFirstTime = false;
                   player.start();
                  }
                  else{
                      player.start();
                  }
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, delay, period);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    player.release();
    tt.cancel();
    timer.cancel();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    player.start();
}
```

}

Comment: H Andrey, could you describe what you did to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To stop the service try this :

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

To stop activity:

```
MyActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: 'this' would be the onclick listener in his code, what he is doing already looks correct, that's why we need to wait for his exceptions from his logs

Comment: i use your proposition but i still have the problem. i'll compile on my android, and update the post. Thanks

Comment: What's on line 51 in MyService.java